# refresh programmatically created composer

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer

I am trying to create a composer using PyQGIS. Everything works as expected. The only difference compared to the manual creation of a composer is, that I am not able to update the layers (by pressing "Refresh View") in the Composer GUI after creating the composer by script which works fine when I create the composer the GUI-way.

My code so far:

```
from PyQt4.QtXml import QDomDocument

template_filePath = "PATH_TO_COMPOSER_TEMPLATE"
template_file = file(template_filePath)
template_content = template_file.read()
template_file.close()
document = QDomDocument()
document.setContent(template_content)
composition.loadFromTemplate(document)
```

Comment: By the way - if I close the project and restart it, the composer and the Refresh View Button behaves normal - I guess I am missing some line of code at the end which sets a specific state of the composer or something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtXml import *

myFile = "PATH_TO_COMPOSER_TEMPLATE"
myTemplateFile = file(myFile, 'rt')
myTemplateContent = myTemplateFile.read()
myTemplateFile.close()
myDocument = QDomDocument()
myDocument.setContent(myTemplateContent, False)
newcomp = iface.createNewComposer()
newcomp.composition().loadFromTemplate(myDocument)
composition = QgsComposition(iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings())
composition.refreshItems()
```